# Filtering a jQuery ListView using Checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I have jQuery ListView that loads data from a php file. I also have a checkbox that onclick should be able to filter the list. The filtering is done by sending a post message to server and refreshing the list. However, the checkbox list is not filtering the list. The code below is only part of the whole implementation. Here is the page:
http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/restaurant_list.html

This is the HTML implementation:

```
<head>
<script>
lastRecord=0;
       function loadRest(){
        $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
        $.get( 
        "queryRestaurantsList.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
        function( data ) {
            $('#rest_mesgs').append( data )
            .listview( 'refresh' );
        }
    );
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadRest()">
<div data-demo-html="true">                
<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<legend>Select your type of Restaurant:</legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" onchange="onfilter()" value="Vegetarian"/>
<label for="checkbox-h-2a">Vegetarian</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div data-demo-html="true">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-split-theme="b" data-split-icon="plus" data-inset="true" id="rest_mesgs">
<li data-role="list-divider">Restaurants</li>   
</ul>
</div>

<script>    
function onfilter(){
 if($("#checkbox-h-2a").prop('checked')){
     document.getElementById("hehe").innerHTML = "if condition is true";
 var a = document.getElementById("checkbox-h-2a");
 $.post("queryRestaurantsList.php",
    {
    filter0 : a.value;
    },
    function(data){
    $('#rest_mesgs').append( data )
    .listview( 'refresh' );
    });
}
    else {
         document.getElementById("hehe").innerHTML = "not working";
    }   
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This is php file:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//Check if POST array is empty or not

if ($_POST == null){

$query = "SELECT Name,Short_Loc,Image_Link,Type FROM Restaurant_Info"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print '<li>';   
        print '<a href="'.$row['Full_Link'].'">';
        print '<img style="height:80px;" src="'.$row['Image_Link'].'">';
        print '<h2 style="text-wrap : normal">'.$row['Name'].'</h2>';
        print '<p id="type" class="ui-li-aside"><strong>'.$row['Type'].'</strong></p>';
        print '<p>'.$row['Short_Loc'].'</p>';
        print '</a>';
        print '</li>';
        }
}

else {

    $value1 = $_POST[filter0];

    $query0 = 'SELECT Name,Short_Loc,Image_Link FROM Restaurant_Info WHERE Type LIKE ';
    $query0 = $query0.'"%'.$value1.'%"';
$result = mysql_query($query0) or die( "Unable to execute query");
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($num_results == 0){
    print "Your criteria does not match any of the restaurants";
}

else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print '<li>';   
    print '<a href="'.$row['Full_Link'].'">';
    print '<img style="height:80px;" src="'.$row['Image_Link'].'">';
    print '<h2 style="text-wrap : normal">'.$row['Name'].'</h2>';
    print '<p>'.$row['Short_Loc'].'</p>';
    print '</a>';
    print '</li>';
}
}
```

Comment: Your code has a serious vulnerability for sql-injection. I suggest you use paremeterized queries and fix this as soon as possible.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user3558931. The checkbox list is not filtering the list

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 errors, but unfortunately I can't test them.

1 - This php part:

```
else {

$value1 = $_POST[filter0];
```

Should be replace with:

```
else {

$value1 = $_POST['filter0'];
```

Otherwise filter0 will be treated as a constant instead of a string.

2 - On your html, you did:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" onchange="onfilter()" value="Vegetarian"/>
```

This should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" onclick="onfilter()" value="Vegetarian"/>
```

I think a checkbox won't fire onchange when you check or uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

1 . To maintain checkbox state change use jQuery.toggle(). It's the safest way.

```
$("#checkbox-h-2a").toggle(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    getListviewItems({filter0: filter});
}, function() {
    getListviewItems();
});
```

2 . Make one function with params for getting list items. That way you'll keep your code clean and easy to maintain.

```
function getListviewItems(opt) {
    opt.filter0 = (opt.filter0 == undefined)?'':opt.filter0;
    /* Body of function, post and/or get calls, etc. */
}
```